Are there laws against over-complying with a subpoena?
If ACME Corp receives a subpoena to provide all documents related to John Doe, does ACME have an requirement to ensure that only documents related to John Doe are produced?
In an effort to be efficient with legal paperwork, ACME would prefer just exporting the dataset associated with Mr. Doe, and don't want to take time combing through it to remove unrelated personal data from other clients.
However if the clients find out that their personal data was released, they will not be happy. Does ACME have any liability here to the other clients, or is ACME in the clear because all that matters is that they comply with the subpoena?

FWIW, I haven't downvoted, (yet...) but I'm considering it for the way the question is framed; specifically the use of "overcomplying" when it's pretty obvious to the reader that you are trying to be difficult and reduce workload by forcing your legal opponent to sort through mountains of irrelevant data.  What you are suggesting is a passive / aggressive act of defiance on par with paying a fine with a wheelbarrow full of pennies.

Do we assume all documents are ACMEs to throw around as they want, or do you want to know if any people mentioned in those documents would sue ACME if they turn something over to the police they did not have to?

Maybe the question would be: how much time or effort will it take for opposing counsel to sort through the records and pick out those requested by the subpoena? The answer might hinge on whether that amount of effort is within reason.

@NateEldredge If one party objects to the manner in which the other carries out discovery, they can enter a motion to that effect, and if the judge agrees and orders the opposing party to shape up, disobeying that order can bring contempt charges. More normally, a party would object to excessive and onerous demands for documents, but a judge's power to manage the case is broad, and I don't see why it wouldn't apply to excessive replies as well.

@nvoigt yes, that is my question. Can ACME get sued by another client whose information was released without reason and without relevance to the subpoena.

united-kingdomeuropean-union
Yes, ACME can be sued by its other clients for releasing their information. To divulge that information ACME needs to establish at least one out of the six lawful bases under the UK GDPR / GDPR. The relevant one here would be GDPR Article 6(1)(c):

processing is necessary for compliance with a legal obligation to
which the controller is subject;

ACME is only under a legal obligation to provide the information it was asked for. The rest is being provided by ACME voluntarily and so the lawful basis isn't established.

Thanks that's interesting, however I am looking for a US-based answer

@Igshost FYI (since I've just answered another of your questions with a non-US answer), the site encourages answers from different jurisdictions to the question in order to make questions more broadly useful to other readers.
